# Asp.net MVC Edit in Place

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

There are already jQuery based Edit in place plug ins available. But i am not sure how can i use them with Asp.net MVC. Any code sample for controller? I want to edit the .aspx files as my web application is not getting text/content from database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you do you don't want to edit the actual .aspx pages, since basically then anyone could add all kinds of code to your application opening you up to all kinds of headaches and security issues. You want to either put that text in the database or you want to write it out to files (either XML, plain text, etc).